# Get all values and associative keys as a flat array from a multidimensional array of variable depth/structure

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

Is there any way to flatten a multidimensional (1 to 3 levels max) with keys?

I have an array like this

```
array(
    'Orange',
    'Grape',
    'Banana' => array(
        'Big',
        'Small'
    ),
    'Apple' => array(
        'Red',
        'Green' => array(
            'Soft',
            'Hard'
        )
    )
);
```

And I want it to be like this

```
array(
    'Orange',
    'Grape',
    'Banana',
    'Big',
    'Small',
    'Apple',
    'Red',
    'Green',
    'Soft',
    'Hard'
);
```

So it will keep the order of appearance in order to lately get indexes with `array_keys`.

I've tried several ways but if the array elements a key for a new array, it wont be flattened, just skipped, so my final array looks like this

```
array:7 [▼
  0 => "Orange"
  1 => "Grape"
  2 => "Big"
  3 => "Small"
  4 => "Red"
  5 => "Soft"
  6 => "Hard"
]
```

Comment: Are you sure all the keys are unique ? You could have "Red" for several fruits, for example...

Comment: [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) could help.

Comment: @Amessihel keys are not unique, but as they are converted to values, there will be no problem, as each key (now values) will have their own numeric key :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a recursive function for that:

```
$nested = array(
    'Orange',
    'Grape',
    'Banana' => array(
        'Big',
        'Small'
    ),
    'Apple' => array(
        'Red',
        'Green' => array(
            'Soft',
            'Hard'
        )
    )
);

function flattern($array)
{
    $flat=[];
    foreach($array as $key=>$val){
        if(is_array($val)){
            $flat[]=$key;
            $flat = array_merge($flat, flattern($val));
        }else{
            $flat[]=$val;
        }
    }
    return $flat;
}

var_dump(flattern($nested));
```

Comment: Or with function return spreading inside of `array_push()` https://3v4l.org/COmDj

Answer (score 0):

Extending the sample input data to include associative elements which contain non-array-type data, it may become important to capture keys if they are non-integers.  Here is a recursive function that works with the original question data and this extended requirement.

Spreading indexed arrays inside of `array_push()` offers real convenience.  If you spread an empty array, no elements are pushed.  By spreading an array inside `array_push()`, the need for `array_merge()` is removed.

Code: [(Demo)](https://3v4l.org/PWr6L)

```
$array = [
    'Orange',
    'Grape',
    'Banana' => [
        'Big',
        'Small'
    ],
    'Apple' => [
        'Red',
        'Green' => [
            'Soft',
            'Hard'
        ]
    ],
    'foo' => [
        [
            [
                'bar0' => 'nun',
                'bar1' => 'won',
                'bar2' => 'too',
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

function flatten(array $array): array
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        array_push(
            $result,
            ...(is_int($k) ? [] : [$k]),
            ...(is_array($v) ? flatten($v) : [$v])
        );
    }
    return $result;
}

var_export(flatten($array));
```

Result:

```
array (
  0 => 'Orange',
  1 => 'Grape',
  2 => 'Banana',
  3 => 'Big',
  4 => 'Small',
  5 => 'Apple',
  6 => 'Red',
  7 => 'Green',
  8 => 'Soft',
  9 => 'Hard',
  10 => 'foo',
  11 => 'bar0',
  12 => 'nun',
  13 => 'bar1',
  14 => 'won',
  15 => 'bar2',
  16 => 'too',
)
```